# Can an AWS Rekognition Custom Label model be deployed to another account?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rekognition

We have a trained custom-labels model with good accuracy in an account(say, development account). We would like to deploy/transfer it to a new account(say, client account), so that further costs on running that model is charged to the client account. How can we deploy the model so that it is tied to the client account? We would really like to avoid re-training a model using the client account..

Any input is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

At present, the only way to setup a model in another AWS account is:

1. Copy over the latest set of annotated (labeled) images in the training and test datasets to the new AWS account.
2. Train a new model.

To copy a dataset from one region to another, please follow the steps outlined in this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/customlabels-dg/dataset-region-transfer.html).

We are constantly working to improve the experience. Please check out these [FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/rekognition/faqs/), and then [contact us](https://pages.awscloud.com/Amazon-Rekognition-Contact-Us-Registration.html), if you have more questions.

Thank you.

Comment: The link provided for copying the dataset is no longer valid. How do we accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use copy-project-version API to copy model and its artifacts into a different AWS account. Not that dataset will not be copied and copied model is not re-trainable in destination account. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/announcing-the-launch-of-the-model-copy-feature-for-amazon-rekognition-custom-labels/